# backtracking and recursion

Tags: java, backtracking

I have a Boolean array which represents a line of light bulbs. True=light on. False=light of.
the rules are if you switch of or on a light bulb un the [i] place, the bulbs in the [i]+1 and [i]-1 changes to, except if it's in the edges then it changes only the one next to it. I need to write a method that receives 2 Boolean arrays and returns true if the switch is possible to get to the second one after doing several actions with the first one. For example:
 'from' array :{true, false, false, true, true, false}

'to' array:{false, false, false, true, false, true}

-this is true because you can change first the bulb un the 1 position then in the 2nd position then in the 4th position.

-I'm not allowed to use loops only recursion, but i don't even what's the logic of the answer ,how am i suppose to predict the series of actions, or what is the base case for the recursion here.

-I'm allowed to use as much as private methods as i want...

-thanks for all repliers!!!

Comment: And what is your question? Do you want us to write the code? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you have problems to code the recursion itself or to find out the stop-criteria?

Comment: If you don't know where to begin, try to solve the problem on paper. Can you for yourself see if you can find a set of operations to get from the `from` state to the `to` state? How did you do it? Can you find a system behind your reasoning? Can you write it down in formal steps? Can you transform these steps in code? Does it use recursion or can you transform it into using recursion?

Comment: problem to code the recursion..iv'e been trying to write on a peace of paper the tree of events and recursion but didn't get to something useful..-if you can help me with the code it would be much appriciated,i'll learn from it a lot..And if not with code so a little bit of guidance about the logic behind the answer of this specific problem, how to check that the 'to' is legal